# Showing transitivity property for global analytic functions

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

According to Ahlfors (Chapter 8), a function element is a pair $(f,\omega)$ where f is defined and analytic over $\omega$. 2 pairs are direct analytic continuations of each other if they are same on their domain of intersection, which is nonempty. He then further considers chains $(f_1,\omega_1), (f_2,\omega_2), \cdots$ where each term is DAC of the next. How to show that this defines an equivalence relation?

The relation is explicitly given by -
$(f_1,\omega_1)$ and $(f_2,\omega_2)$ are $\textbf{equivalent}$ if $\omega_1 \cap \omega_2 \neq \phi$ and $f_1=f_2$ on $\omega_1 \cap \omega_2$

My main question is regarding showing the transitivity condition. Can someone please tell?

Comment: Please someone tell something

Comment: Equivalence relation on what? On the chains? And what is the relation?

Comment: Yes, on the chains. Relation is what has been defined. $(f_1,\omega_1)$ and $(f_2,\omega_2)$ are equivalent if $\omega_1 \cap \omega_2 \neq \phi$ and $f_1=f_2$ on $\omega_1 \cap \omega_2$

Comment: So by "Yes, on the chains" you mean "No, on the pairs". Got it. What's $\omega$ in $(f,\omega)$? A connected open subset (of something)?

Comment: Are all $\omega$ assumed to be open and connected? Without it the relationship is not transitive. And with this it follows from the uniqueness of analytic continuation.

Comment: Yes, they are open connected subsets of the complex plane

Comment: Like, if we are given that $(f_1,\omega_1)~(f_2,\omega_2)$ and $(f_2,\omega_2) \sim (f_3,\omega_3)$, how can we say $(f_1,\omega_1) ~\sim (f_3\omega_3)$? Is it by uniqueness of analytic continuation?

Comment: The relation $\sim$ is not transitive. Consider, for instance, $\omega_1=\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \Re z>0\}$, $\omega_2=\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \Im z>0\}$, $\omega_3=\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \Re z<0\lor \Im z<0\}$, $f_1(z)=\ln\lvert z\rvert+i\arctan\frac {\Im z}{\Re z}$, $f_2(z)=\ln\lvert z\rvert+i\arccos\frac{\Re z}{\lvert z\rvert}$, $f_3(z)=\begin{cases}\ln\lvert z\rvert+i\arccos\frac{\Re z}{\lvert z\rvert}&\text{if }\Im z>0\\ \ln\lvert z\rvert+i\left(2\pi-\arccos\frac{\Re z}{\lvert z\rvert}\right)&\text{if }\Im z\le0\end{cases}$. Its transitive closure is another matter.